# Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value

Tags: mysql

How to find 02 different values from same column name. My sql query is as under

SELECT * FROM `table1` where  month = 'JUNE' & 'MAY';

I want the values of both June and May month data

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

month = 'JUNE' & 'MAY'; - in sql you can't link in this way either repeat or use in

eg month = 'june' OR month = 'may'

alternatively month in('june','may')

nb & is incorrect month cannot be both june and may.